# Metasploitable: Change/Location of login page file?

Tags: authentication, server, metasploit, metasploitable

I have been messing around with Metasploitable 2 and changed the default login credentials.

The login page looks like this:
[image: Metasploitable 2 Screenshot]

I want to change where it says "Login with msfadmin/msfadmin to get started" to my credentials.
Is it possible to edit this file? If so, where is the file located?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been awhile since I've played with this and it can be distro specific but try looking in `/etc/issue` as mentioned [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-login-message/).